# Android postioning of a view

Tags: android, view, position

I have created CustomView. The view is higher in size than the screen. So it is showing fully in the device screen.

I want to determine position to determine how much it is outside the screen in left, right top and bottom. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

For what purpose you want to know how much of your view is outside of the screen? Can't you just use [Scroller](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Scroller.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can call getLocalVisibleRect on the view to get the "on screen" rectangle.

For example say in your onDraw

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Rect r=new Rect();
    getLocalVisibleRect(r);
    // 0 to r.top is above the visible screen, etc
    ...
```

Once you have that rect it should be simple to calculate the values you want.